# DataServiceProcessingPipeline.ProcessedRequest is called before operation is complete

Tags: wcf, service, odata, idispatchmessageinspector

I'm using OData over WCF Data service. DataServiceProcessingPipeline.ProcessedRequest event is called before the odata call completion. 
For example: For the following URI, ProcessedRequest gets called immediately before it returns the data.
http://somehost//odata/v3/data/Products()

I'm looking for intercepting the incoming and outgoing request so that I can limit the number of OData calls (method and data calls) coming from the specific client. It's the same issue even with the IDispatchMessageInspector::BeforeSendReply method override.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: FYI, the logic I'm using is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446728/how-to-throttle-wcf-service-per-client but at endpoint level. IDispatchMessageInspector::BeforeSendReply works fine in the context of method(service operation) call but not for data calls